# Amazon api product listing says 'could not connect to amazon', while replace 'com' with 'in' in aws_signed_request() function

Tags: php, api, amazon-product-api

I'm using Amazon API for product listing in my php(joomla) website.

Files included:

> amazon_api_class.php
>
> aws_signed_request.php
>
> [files download link](https://www.jahajee.com/PHP-Amazon-Product-advertising-API-tutorial/13569/1.html)

Im getting response when I use **"com" as region**

```
private function queryAmazon($parameters)
    {
    return aws_signed_request("com", $parameters, $this->public_key, $this->private_key, $this->associate_tag);
    }
```

When I replace **"com" with "in"**, im getting **error that "could not connect to amazon"** and it returns empty value.

```
private function queryAmazon($parameters)
    {
    return aws_signed_request("in", $parameters, $this->public_key, $this->private_key, $this->associate_tag);
    }
```

I need to list the products **from amazon.in not from amazon.com**